# Create a thumb and original image

Tags: laravel

in my controller very simply I load an image like this:

```
// upload original
$path = $request->file('thumb')->store('thumbs');
```

However, I want to create a thumbnail of predefined size (for example 100x100), using the same name created automatically .. adding only "_thumb" to the name.

I use the library http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction

Comment: The documentation of the package explains it here: http://image.intervention.io/api/resize

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following code

Adding this in header section

```
use ImageResize;
```

And in your **controller** use following code

```
$photoThumbnail   = ImageResize::make($request->file('thumb'))
    ->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio(); } )
    ->encode('jpg',100);

Storage::disk('thumbnail')->put("your_image_name", $photoThumbnail);
```

In your `app/config` folder `filesystems.php` add this configuration

```
'thumbnail' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/thumbnail'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'permissions' => [
            'file' => [
                'public' => 0664,
                'private' => 0600,
            ],
            'dir' => [
                'public' => 0775,
                'private' => 0700,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

You have to configure also `app\config` folder `app.php` file `provider` section

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

and `aliases` section use

```
'ImageResize' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
```

[For More Details](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)