# Intervention Image not detecting image

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm using Intervention Image in my laravel app.

I upload a base64 string image through an ajax request, and then I convert that into a regular image.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'avatar' => 'required',
]);         

$image_file = $request->get('avatar');

list($type, $image_file) = explode(';', $image_file);
list(, $image_file)      = explode(',', $image_file);
$avatar = base64_decode($image_file);
```

Now, this works fine. In fact, if I go to save the image, it opens up just fine on my local like any other image. Great.

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($avatarPath.'/avatars/avatar.png', $avatar);
```

The problem is that when I try to pass the image into intervention image, like so

```
$image = Image::make($avatar)->fit(150, 150);
```

it just returns an image with all the properties being null. If I save the image, it just saves as a 0KB image with no data.

This does not return any errors.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is `$image` a mistake; should you have `$avatar` there?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes sorry, I was testing saving the intervention image

Comment: You follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110644/create-a-thumb-and-original-image/67110865#67110865

Comment: @A.ANoman that helped! Thx

Comment: @FelixMaxime, It' s my pleasure. Pls add a comment comment that answer